# How to solve many to many relationship in sql server with lazy loading (entity framework)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

i am new in asp.net. i am trying to make a student course management project using mvc. so here a student has many courses and many students under one course. i am facing a very odd problem at the time of doing that.
here is the problem [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd20t.jpg)

and for further information i am attaching the model classes of student and course
[Student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd20t.jpg)
[Course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppXep.jpg)
in the sql server the models are like [Course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwMTg.jpg), [Student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2jsO.jpg) and the mapping table like [CourseStudent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hYgp.jpg).

The relationship of CourseStudent , Student and Course like [mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhpwr.jpg),
[Course To CourseStudent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofBZI.jpg)  and [Student to CourseStudent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM9of.jpg).

when the ids of student course table all are normally ID then it seems ok during lazy loading but when i make the name of ID as StudentID or ID as CourseID it makes that error.

**Model code**

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

public ActionResult Index() {

 DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext(); 
 //var x = db.Courses.Include(i => i.Students).Where(i => i.CourseID == 1).Single(); 
 var x = db.Courses.Include(i=>i.Students).Where(i=>i.CourseID==1).Si‌​ngle();
 var y = db.Students.Include(i => i.Courses).Where(i => i.StudentID == 1).Single(); 

 return View(); 
 } 
}
```

That problem is bothering me. I want a solution.
Thank You
Here is my Model Code with error when debugging[image: code], context class is here [image: context class] and finally error showing in browser[image: problem]

Comment: can you put your models code on your post without images ?

Comment: and code of `EF query` and the `context class` ? what is your `Error` ?

Comment: As far as I know, EF by default matches to `ID` names (without prefixes) when creating relationships. By the way, why do you need the name `StudentID` in a entity named `Student`? Isn't just `ID` self-explanatory enough?

Comment: @Sampath Here is my Model code
`public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
            //var x = db.Courses.Include(i => i.Students).Where(i => i.CourseID == 1).Single();

            var x = db.Courses.Include(i=>i.Students).Where(i=>i.CourseID==1).Single();
            var y = db.Students.Include(i => i.Courses).Where(i => i.StudentID == 1).Single();


            return View();
        }
}`

Comment: that is not the models code.it's your `ef query`.can you update your original post with those details.don't paste it to comment section.no one can see that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up a complex many to many relationship in entity framework 4 code first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876979/how-to-set-up-a-complex-many-to-many-relationship-in-entity-framework-4-code-fir)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to use the fluent API to set up the many to many mapping with the names of the FKs you have in the database.

Something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasMany(x => x.Students).WithMany(x=>x.Courses).Map(x=>
    {
        x.ToTable("CourseStudent");
        x.MapLeftKey("Course_ID");
        x.MapRightKey("Student_ID");
    };
}
```

This tells EF about the structure of your map table

Acccording to ([Mapping a Many-to-Many relationship with an Attribute in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505755/mapping-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-an-attribute-in-entity-framework)) there is no attribute alternative to this configuration

On a side note, I personally think that lazy loading is a bad idea in a web application, you are much better off if you eager load using .Include as you will avoid perfomance issues where you go to the database multiple times under a single request.